# jQuery Calendar event-clicks not firing with ftLab fast click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am working with AngularJS calendar (Which is essentially jQuery Full Calendar by Adam Shaw wrapped for angular).  Here, the calendar event-item clicks worked both in ipad and desktop fine, until I brought in fastclick.js by ft labs (https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick). Now, calendar event-item clicks works only on desktop, but not working at all on the ipad!

However, other ng-clicks work fine with fastclick both on desktop and iPad.

I understand how fastclick.js works by simply adding touch-end event listeners and calling click events within them, and cannot understand why this would fail with calendar event-item clicks.

Note: I tried using ngTouch instead of fastclick, but their, the ng-click doesn't become fast. According to google, ngTouch's ng-click cannot be used with jQuery

Comment: Have you tried adding the `needsclick` class as [specified in the fastclick documentation](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick#ignore-certain-elements-with-needsclick)?

Comment: Can you update with code samples? or fiddle?

Comment: Where did you include the JS? Try to include in the header before anything else.

Comment: I recommend to use vclick from jquery mobile

Comment: While I have not specifically tried what you are doing, I have had fun with events.  When you bind events, they are cumulative unless you unbind previous bindings for a given event.  This can produce unexpected results if you're not careful.  Another thing, if you bind to a top level DOM element, your clicks (and I guess touches) should bubble up.  I use this for complex grids as it reduces bindings and memory use and improves overall performance.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

if all else fails you can inspect which events are linked to your elements with visual event: http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event 
This adds an overlayer to any web page and let you visually inspect the JS code that's linked to an element (it shows you the piece of code in a pop up).

this way you can easily see if everything is set up correctly.

PS: I have no link to this tool or it's makers.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. `fastclickjs` blocks every jQuery `.click()` . But if you dispatch event without jQuery everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is an old question, but maybe it helps somebody.

I had a similar problem, and even `fastclick.js` didn't help and wasn't fast enough on the iPad.

The problem is that on a normal browser click event (on an iPad) has a delay of 300ms on touchstart and again 300ms on touchend.

`fastclick.js` also had some conflicts like yours with the calendar.

So i just wrote an own directive and called it `ng-mobile-click`.

**Directive ngMobileClick:**

```
App.directive("ngMobileClick", [function () {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind("touchstart click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            scope.$apply( attrs["ngMobileClick"] );
        });
    }
}]);
```

**Usage in templates:**

```
<input type="button" value="somevalue" ng-mobile-click="someFunction(someParam)"/>
```

**Advantage:**
Will never conflict with standard click events.

**Disadvantage**
You have to refactor your code where you need it